# Magento Paypal redirect to Cart Page

Tags: magento, paypal

I have two questions

1. I have a website in magento. I am using paypal for payment gateway. In checkout page paypal redirect to cart page. I just googled and found some solutions but none worked. Here I am using Mexico paypal extension also.
2. In admin while entering the sandbox box details to paypal like API username and password and etc, finally clicks on save config values are not updating. showing default values like some *********

Please any one help me?

Comment: Hi Mohan- that is correct. Magento encrypts the API credentials for you, I wouldn't worry about that. That's good. As far as #1 is concerned, this is now how it's supposed to work. What payment method did you integrate, standard or Express Checkout?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Hi, Geek Ninja Iam using PayPal Website Payments Standard.

Comment: can you disable extension & check ?